# Cannot Read Property 'Map' Of Undefined When Mapping out Array

Tags: sql, arrays, react-native

Running a Fetch from SQL to React Native, then Mapping the result to display a list of the results. but when i do its coming up with the error Cannot Read Property 'map' of undefined

```
InsertRecord=()=>{
    var insertAPIURL = "MyurlAPI";
    var headers={
      'Accept':'application/json',
      'Content-Type' : 'application.json'
    }
    fetch(insertAPIURL,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers
      }
      ).then((Response)=>Response.json())
      .then((Response)=>{
         global.post = Response;
      });

       
  }
  InsertRecord();
```

the result from the server is:

[{"text":"helloworld","user":"emocentric"},{"text":"Dbdhd","user":"emocentric"},{"text":"helloworld","user":"emocentric"}]

then I map out the array to display all "text" fields

```
 const arrayDataItems = global.post.map(cpost => 
      <Text>{cpost.text}</Text>
  )
```

then display that in my app js

```
<Text style={styles.caption}>

        {arrayDataItems}
         
        
        </Text>
```

but when i do it comes back with an error of:
Cannot Read Property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Wouldn't you read from the response, not the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Because Ui is rendering before data is set to `global` or `global.post`.

Have a condition that if global is not null then render the map function.
Multiple ways to check it, ie

```
{if (globla){
global.post.map(cpost=> 
      <Text>{cpost.text}</Text>
  )
}
```

or

```
 const arrayDataItems = global?.post?.map(cpost=> 
      <Text>{cpost.text}</Text>
  )
```

or

```
{global.post && global.post.map(/remaining code/) }
```